# Join 4 tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four tables and the structures are:

```
//Table Person
SSN (PK) | name
123456789 | AA
234567890 | BB

//Table Teacher
teacher_id (PK) |  SSN
1 | 123456789
2 | 234567890

//Table Lesson_a
lesson_id (PK) | teacher_id
101 | 1
102 | 1
103 | 2

//Table Lesson_b
lesson_id (PK) | teacher_id
111 | 1
112 | 1
113 | 2
```

And I got this so far, after I joined the first 3 tables:

```
person.name | teacher_id | number of lessons
AA | 1 | 2
BB | 2 | 1
```

But I want to get:

```
person.name | teacher_id | number of lessons
AA | 1 | 4
BB | 2 | 2
```

And I've gotten this far:

```
SELECT 
person.name, 
person.name,
COUNT(teacher.teacher_id) AS "No of lessons" 
FROM teacher
INNER JOIN lesson_a
ON teacher.teacher_id = lesson_a.teacher_id
INNER JOIN person 
ON person.ssn = teacher.ssn
GROUP BY teacher.teacher_id, lesson.teacher_id
ORDER BY teacherr.teacher_id ;
```

How should I join the last table lesson_b at the right way?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` before you aggregate:

```
select p.name, count(*)
from person p join
     teacher t
     on p.ssn = t.ssn join
     (select teacher_id from lesson_a union all
      select teacher_id from lesson_b
     ) l
     on l.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
group by p.name, p.ssn;
```

Some comments on the data model.  Splitting the lessons into two tables seems like a very bad choice for the data model.  There should be one table for `lessons` with a column specifying "a" or "b".

Perhaps worse is using `ssn` as a key in the `person` table.  SSNs are personally identifiable information (PII) and should be protected when stored in databases -- even if the laws in your particular jurisdiction don't actually require such protection.